# Prevent certain rating on RatingBar

Tags: android

Rating bar has a `OnRatingBarChangeListener` which worked only when the rating is already been changed by the user. I want when the user click on the rating bar to put a 3 star rating, `RatingBar` prompts a `Toast` that 3 star rating is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

this code will help you.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating);
        RatingBar ratingBar;
        ratingBar = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(rating == 3){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3 star rating is not allowed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ratingBar.setRating(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

U can get the rating set by the user through the onRatingBarChangedListener in the onRatingChanged method.

```
ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
        boolean fromUser) {

        if(rating == 3){
             //show toast here. then may be reset rating to 0.
        }

     }
});
```